# Passing a parameter from query multiple times and invoking SSRS report

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

There is an SSRSreport connecting to Oracle DB and it has one date parameter. Is it possible to create a data driven subscription and call it and pass multiple date parameters from a query so that every time a date parameter is passed report gets invoked for each date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the subscription will run a copy of the report for each row that the data-driven query returns. So they can each be run with a different date parameter value.

Comment: Can you please provide an example Steve?

Comment: You just select the dates you want from the tables you want. There's no code involved, just a query. If you have specific questions about how to design the query, that would be a separate issue that would require much more detail.

Comment: Thanks Steve, do you mean go to create data driven subscription and write my query to select values from table and then pass it later?

Comment: When you get to Step 4 of the data-driven subscription setup there is a "To email" field. Set that to "use value from query" and then select the email column from your query.

Comment: Thank you, i was able to create one.

Comment: @Shashi Glad this helped, please mark it as answered.